# Does your Karma level affect random encounter rate?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout New Vegas, you'll come across insects, raiders, random enemies, etc.

Does your Karma level affect how many times this happens, and does it affect the type of enemy you encounter?

Comment: No, Karma increases only your happiness rate and has nothing to do with encounters. Oh wait, there are other games then the [Kittens game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kittens-game)

Comment: @Mathias711 What are you talking about?  I stated that it was in Fallout :/

Comment: Just kidding man. That's why it is in a comment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Karma isn't as important in FNV as it was in FO3.
In FO3, it was part of a 'faction system' (of sorts) where you got certain benefits and disadvantages from being good/evil. The benefits/disadvantages were mostly the same, it simply determined who gave them to you/attacked you (eg. regulators or talon company attacking you, etc.).

In FNV, this has been changed to the faction/reputation system, where each individual faction checks the good and bad things you've done (from their point of view). Karma is used for certain perks. It MIGHT have an effect on the reaction you get from certain NPCs like in FO3, though I'm not sure it does.

I don't think it has any effect on spawns, though the faction system does (if you're hated by the legion/NCR, they'll send hit squads).

EDIT: Karma will affect your interactions with certain NPCs. For example, Cass will leave you if you talk to her a few times while evil (she'll give you a few warnings and a bit of time to better yourself, but if you ignore those, she'll leave).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, although I appreciate the extra information.

Comment: @Ataxia Updated my post

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give it a little more time in order to get any more possible answers, then I'll accept your answer.